# Git log format error

Tags: git, git-log, git-config

When I type `git log`, it shows:

```
ESC[33m0136a75  ESC[34m%>(12)Fri Feb 10 07:19:55 2017   
ESC[32m%<(7)Tran Le     
ESC[31m (HEAD, origin/jpt-dev, jpt-dev) 
ESC[mImprove search in jpTlogMonitor
ESC[33m809b3a9  ESC[34m%>(12)Wed Feb 8 09:54:38 2017    
ESC[32m%<(7)Tien Pham   ESC[31m ESC[mFix jpTgenNetconf_SUITE test_timeout testcase
ESC[33me366d23  ESC[34m%>(12)Tue Feb 7 10:33:57 2017
```

So I think something wrong in my config. What is the main reason?

Comment: Your terminal cannot understand ANSI colors.

Comment: What system / terminal do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @poke commented : what you see are escape sequences (see for example [this link](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes)), which should be interpreted by your terminal as signals to say "display the following text in yellow", "display the following text in bold", etc ...

- you can try another terminal (e.g : git bash under windows),
- git should turn off colors if it detects it is not writing to a terminal :

  ```
  $ git log | less
  ```
- or you can tell git to *never* display colors on your PC :

  ```
  $ git config --global color.ui false
  ```

  ( see the documentation : [Colors in git](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_colors_in_git) )